# Scala Compiler doesn't compile in ScalaIDE

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, scala-ide, scalac

I'm trying to develop on the Scala compiler project with the help of ScalaIDE. I followed [this guide](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/scalac-trunk/index.html) to set up the development environment. When I now try to build the mentioned projects, the *reflect* project won't get built. Instead, I get the following error via the console output:

```
uncaught exception during compilation: scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError    reflect     Unknown Scala Problem
```

Having tried the provided ANT script of the project via the console, everything seems to work fine.

Does anyone know if I'm missing a hidden compiler flag, dependency or something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the IDE for Scala 2.10 you can only build the 2.10.x branch of the Scala compiler. If you want to work on `master`, you need to install a 2.11-based version of the IDE. We don't publicise IDE for 2.11 nightlies yet, but they are available at:

http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly/scala-ide-master-2.11.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thanks, I just switched to the 2.10.x branch and added the *fjbg* project and the build process worked.